# On the Peach Aviation website, is there a way to set the currency?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, japan, peach-aviation

On the [Peach Aviation website](http://www.flypeach.com/?lang=en) I keep getting prices quoted in either Taiwanese or Hong Kong dollars or Japanese yen.

I am actually looking up prices for flights from Taipei and Hong Kong so it makes some sense.

But I thought most airline websites have some way for the user to change the currency used to quote ticket prices. On this website I can't find it. Am I simply blind or is it just a missing feature of this site?

I'm only interested in the currencies displayed because it makes it easier to compare prices. Comparing HKD and TWD in my head is tricky. (I'm not concerned with which currency tickets would be paid in.)

Comment: *"But most airline websites have some way for the user to change the currency used to quote ticket prices."* Really? Those I am familiar with always quote prices in the currency of the country of departure, as Peach does.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, by the way. Do you want prices to be converted to another currency for information, or to actually be charged in another currency? The latter is almost certainly not possible.

Comment: You could try a browser plugin like this for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-currency-converter/anbfhidldjknonaihbalghlebaijealk?hl=en

Comment: I just want to see the prices in another currency so I don't have to keep converting in a calculator. I'll edit. Maybe I'm used to flight search engines and they are different regarding currency display. If that's the case and I'm just a big dummy then that's an acceptable answer (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to flypeach [fees and charges information](http://www.flypeach.com/sp/en/lm/fares/fees_and_charges/international):

> Fees and charges are quoted in the currency of your first point of
>   origin

This is typical for airline websites, but online travel agents often allow you to book in the currency of your choice.

If you wish to view the price in an alternate currency, then you could install a web page currency conversion plugin.

Comment: I'm such a dummy (-:

Comment: Actually, online travel agents book in the currency of the country where they are located, although presumably some bigger ones may have offices in more than one country. Airlines for some reason usually insist that tickets be booked through their office in the country of departure, which of course only accepts payment in the local currency.

Comment: @fkraiem I agree they do book in currency of PoS, but they often have a currency conversion option. As a counterpoint, AA lets you book on their UK site in GBP for US originating travel.